# Nginx overrides my domain name with ip

Tags: nginx, dns, vps

I have 2 sites running under one VPS. Also I've to domains pointing to that VPS. I can open my sites via domain name, but after opening, domain name is overwritten by VPS ip in browser address bar.

here are few config files:

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost ubuntu1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

and almost identical nginx.conf of both sites:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.example1.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/exapmle1/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and second:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.example2.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/exapmle2/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159998/omniauth-nginx-unicorn-callback-to-wrong-host-url/16218320#16218320 but it's looks like you're already setting the Host header....either the config isn't being applied, or something else weird is happening.

Comment: I suspect this is something which done by your backend, not by nginx. Try logging $upstream_http_location to see when it happens. Also it's good idea to make sure you've cleared browser cache before testing.